# Pandas: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are several posts around about this, I know. But I really can't figure this out, and no one has the exact case as I'm stuck with.

I got this error message:

> /data/src/dataprocessing/eventVw.py:67: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>
> df[label] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,label])

However, I'm already using `.loc` (and `.copy() as other posts suggest`).

`df.loc[:,label] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,label]).copy()`

`df.loc[:,'col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,col1])`

`df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,col1])`

None of these work. What I'm I doing wrong here? Is it not possible to assign values to an existing variable, `df`?

Comment: df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df[col1]) also df is subdataframe from some others , so do copy when you slice df

Comment: Does it mean that somewhere in my code Im using df[something] without .copy() ?